# Returning webpage layout based on if statement

Tags: reactjs

I want to return some webpage layout based upon up to 30 different conditional statements. In my example, I will just give one, so that it makes sense.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import { personSafety } from './modals/PersonSafety';

export default function TagContent(props) {
  if (props.tagText === 'Person is unsafe') {
    return <personSafety />;
  }
}
```

If the tagText='Person is unsafe', I want it to show some webpage code from the file personSafety.

My code from the page PersonSafety.js is below.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Typography } from '@material-ui/core';

export const personSafety = `
      <Typography gutterBottom>
         Person is not very safe
      </Typography>`;
```

I think I am doing this all wrong because it is not working.

What do I need to do to get this working?

Comment: Why is it not working? What is the error message?

Comment: Not an answer but advice, '30 different conditional statements' sounds like a design alarm to me. Don't have enough context here to suggest the right answer, better in a separate question perhaps.

As a starter, try to use `tagText` to build and render the message using a generic component or maintain a JSON/Map of pairs of condition as key and message as value.

For completely different component per condition, [Object Literal lookups](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/deprecating-the-switch-statement-for-object-literals)
 would be a better choice.

Comment: @Indigo You bring up an important point. I've spent ages trying to work out the correct way to do this. Essentially, I am creating context sensitive help that pops up in a modal dialog box. It takes the text from the Material UI Chip (what I call a tag), and reads that to decide what help text (+ diagrams) to display. These diagrams will take data from some variables (+ state) to alter the diagrams. Given the above, could I still do that with a JSON/Map? I've never done one before so in the dark.

Comment: @Jon please create a new question with sample code and detailed context, so the community can help with better answers that will be helpful to others too. You can link the question here.

For a quick answer, if your Chips/Tags are fixed, then you can use an object where tags are keys and each key holds another object as a value. The value object may contain text and a function that will return the diagram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You'll need to name PersonSafety with a name that starts with a capital letter, since otherwise `personSafety` is considered an HTML tag by JSX.
- You'll need to make PersonSafety a true component function if you wish to use it with `<PersonSafety />`.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Typography } from '@material-ui/core';

export const PersonSafety = () => (
  <Typography gutterBottom>
    Person is not very safe
  </Typography>
);
```

You can now do

```
import { PersonSafety } from './modals/PersonSafety';

export default function TagContent(props) {
  if (props.tagText === 'Person is unsafe') {
    return <PersonSafety />;
  }
}
```

Comment: Right, I've gotcha. I did have it as a function before, but have been playing around and changed it to a constant. What you said makes perfect sense. I will give that a go as a possible solution. Still not sure, based on some comments on my original post, although your suggest looks like it is the solution to the question I asked.